# ant's java task can't find a jar in the jre/lib/ext directory

Tags: java, ant, jar

I put "stax-utils.jar" in the extensions directory ([JAVA_HOME]/jre/lib/ext), but ant's java task can't find it, giving:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javanet/staxutils/IndentingXMLStreamWriter
```

Strangely, it works for compilation: ant's **javac** task *can* find it.  The problem is only with running code, with ant's **java** task...

- If I use java from the command line, the jar is found and I can use classes from it.
- If I explicitly give ant the classpath to that specific jar in the extension directory, it also works.

(I've seen this problem before, with one of the XML libraries.)

Comment: Is it javanet.staxutils... or java.net.staxutils..?

Comment: The former (and it works for compilation, and from the command line, suggesting it is successfully accessing the jar and classes).  http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/XML/stax-utils/javanet/staxutils/IndentingXMLStreamWriter.java.htm

Answer (score 0):

try adding it to ANT_HOME/lib

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you use the JVM corresponding to your JAVA_HOME?

Comment: yes.  <echo>${java.home}</echo> gives the jre that contains the lib/ext/staxutils.jar file

Comment: actually... you seem to be right... I did a little more hunting, and <echo>${java.vm.version}</echo> gives 10.0-b19... but the commandline java -version gives 1.6.0_04-b12  The weird thing is that I don't have build 10 installed (unless eclipse or netbeans installed it somewhere when I tried them out).

Comment: correction: 10.0-b19 is from "Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 10.0-b19, mixed mode, sharing)", and I've confirmed that that is the one in JAVA_HOME (by going to the dir, and typing "./java -version"

Comment: It should be in JAVA_HOME/lib/ext, not jre/lib/ext.  I think you are putting it in the wrong location.

What is the reason that you want to have it in lib/ext?  It will give you this problem MANY times over...

Comment: @Thorbjørn I have no preference: but JAVA_HOME/lib/ext does not exist in my Java 1.6 installation.  The only ext I could find was in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext.  I'll try creating the directory you suggest (but I think if it was meant to me there, the installation would have created it).

Comment: @Thorbjørn No, that didn't help.  Consider also that placing it where I did works for java (so it must be correct).  The only problem is with ant.

Comment: So the JVM invoked by the javac task is right, but the JVM which ant is started in is not.

I would investigate how your "ant" is invoked and which JVM the ant invoker script use.

Answer (score 0):

It is too late .. But I was wondering the cause of this ...

As it is related to classloading by the JVM ... And this class loading is related to CLASSPATH .. I think the CLASSPATH had not been set caused the problm long time back...

Donot know abt the present.